# bag migration, fill new field with incrementing counter

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to fill a new message field in an old bag data with an incrementing counter using a bag migration rules file (http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/migration) and rosbag fix?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204390/bag-migration,-fill-new-field-with-incrementing-counter/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep it is (as simple as it should be)! Just create a counter and increment and assign it i update()

Snippet of the migration rules class, ( see http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/migration ) :

```
migrated_types = [  ]

valid = True

counter = 0
  
def update(self, old_msg, new_msg):
    self.counter += 1
    new_msg.obj_id = self.counter
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0